# Create a 2-dimensional NumPy array with 1 row and 2 columns

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is it possible to create a 2-dimensional NumPy array with 1 row and 2 columns (row vector)?

This is what I'm doing ([from the documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#how-to-convert-a-1d-array-into-a-2d-array-how-to-add-a-new-axis-to-an-array)), but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it in one (easier) step:

```
X_new2 = np.array([8.5,156])
X_new2 = X_new2[np.newaxis, :]
```

I've also tried:

```
X_new2 = np.array([[8.5], [156]])
```

But this is returning a column instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to achieve the same result as in your example:

```py
X_new2 = np.array([[8.5,156]])
```

(Notice the extra `[` and `]` to make the array the correct shape.)

Comment: Thanks, those square brackets are hard to understand, I mean, when to open and close them and when to use them at all - I have hard time to get the logic

Comment: `[[8.5,156]]` by itself is a list containing one item, another list.   The array display also mirrors the nested list.  `X_new2.tolist()` actually returns a (nested) list.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
print(y.shape)
```

Comment: thanks, but I get an error (x is unknown)